# Compiler returns error "char *(int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'" even though data returned seems to match function return type

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Am just learning C and this is my first time on *stackoverflow* so am not sure if this is the right to ask this question because it seems trivial compared to the others around here but I found this piece of code in a text book and when I tried to compile in Visual studio I get this:

```
**error C2040: 'menutext' : 'char *(int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'**
```

To be honest I've looked at the code and I don't get why it the compiler is complaining. I really need some help on this. Here's the code:

```
/*********************************************************/
/* */
/* MENU : program which prints out a menu */
/* */
/*********************************************************/
main ()
{ 
  int str_number;
  for (str_number = 0; str_number < 13; str_number++)
  {
    printf ("%s",menutext(str_number));
  }
}
/*********************************************************/
char *menutext(int n) /* return n-th string ptr */
{
  static char *t[] =
  {
    " -------------------------------------- \n",
    " | ++ MENU ++ |\n",
    " | ~~~~~~~~~~~~ |\n",
    " | (1) Edit Defaults |\n",
    " | (2) Print Charge Sheet |\n",
    " | (3) Print Log Sheet |\n",
    " | (4) Bill Calculator |\n",
    " | (q) Quit |\n",
    " | |\n",
    " | |\n",
    " | Please Enter Choice |\n",
    " | |\n",
    " -------------------------------------- \n"
  };
  return (t[n]);
}
```

Comment: In addition to the other comments, all string literal pointers should be const, as modifying them is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not prototype your function `menutext()` and thus C defaults to a return type of `int`.  This will cause `printf()` to complain (error in your case) because it's expecting its second arg to be of type `char *`, not of type `int`.

Add the following two lines *above* the call to `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Needed for the call to printf() */
char *menutext(int); /* Prototype for menutext() */
```

Also, `main()` should always return type `int` and if you're not going to pass in any arguments you should pass in `void` to explicitly state that intention.  Thus the top half of your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Needed for the call to printf() */ 
char *menutext(int); /* Prototype for menutext() */

int main(void)
{
   /* main code here */
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. I'd forgotten about the compiler assuming 'extern int' and even if I'd thought about I just thought that when it got to the function definition it would disregard the 'extern int' assumption and assume the correct type. Again, thanks.